# How to Provide user control in web application in spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

Requirement is only admin should have access to audit report button on UI and for any user other button should not be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean variable in your form backing bean called showAuditReport. In your controller, set this variable to true or false based on the user role. Use this variable to hide/display the button on the UI